# optimization for mass sql insert

Tags: mysql, zend-framework, pdo

I have to insert 100k+ record in the db and I have some memory issues. $_data is an array holding the arrays of data. I even increase the memory size but still got into problems

```
// VERSION 1
protected function save() {

    $memory_limit = ini_get('memory_limit');
    ini_set('memory_limit', '512M');

    $sql = "
        INSERT INTO table (
            c1,
            c2,
            c3,
            c4,
            c5,
            c6,
            c7,
            c7,
            c9,
            c10,
            c11             
        ) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)
        ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE 
            c10 = VALUES(c10),
            c11 = VALUES(c10),
            c12 = VALUES(c12)
    ";
    $db = Zend_Registry::get('db');
    $stmt = new Zend_Db_Statement_Pdo($db, $sql);
    foreach($this->_data as $entry){
        $stmt->execute($entry);
    }
    unset($this->_data, $stmt, $sql);
    ini_set('memory_limit', $memory_limit);
```

The second tries to insert all entries in a multi-insert, but not better.

```
// VERSION 2
protected function save2(){
    $question_marks = str_repeat('?,', count($this->_data[0]));
    $question_marks = trim($question_marks, ',');
    $question_marks = str_repeat("($question_marks),", count($this->_data));
    $question_marks = trim($question_marks, ',');
    $sql = "
        INSERT INTO table (
            c1,
            c2,
            c3,
            c4,
            c5,
            c6,
            c7,
            c7,
            c9,
            c10,
            c11             
        ) VALUES $question_marks
        ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE 
            c10 = VALUES(c10),
            c11 = VALUES(c11),
            c12 = VALUES(c12)
        ;";
    $db = Zend_Registry::get('db');
    $stmt = new Zend_Db_Statement_Pdo($db, $sql);
    $insert_values = call_user_func_array('array_merge', $this->_data);
    $stmt->execute($insert_values);
    $affected_rows = $stmt->rowCount();
    if ($affected_rows){
        // @todo log    
    } 
    unset($this->_data);
    unset($stmt, $sql, $insert_values, $affected_rows, $question_marks);
```

Column names are not the original. 
Any suggestions?

---

I will try to split the data array to 5k entries and do the inserts in batches. Also trying to see how modifying max_allowed_packet in mysql cnf helps.
Meanwhile I would appreciate any suggestions. Thanks

**UPDATE**

*in my case* modifying the max_allowed_packet from 16M to 1024M helped and I did make the insert without splitting the array.

Answer (score 1):

How do you know you have memory problems and not script execution timeouts?

Anyway, I would try with the simple [mysql_query](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php)

Also, take a look and make sure to not have memory leaks on the part that reads the data and prepares it for insert into DB

Comment: sometimes the script stalls and sometimes: Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 1061158912 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 28 bytes). do you think there is a significant difference between mysqli::query() (behind the zend) and mysql_query? mysqli is much more recent and was supposed to be faster.

Answer (score 1):

In complement to @Tudor Constantin answer and as you ask for other suggestions:

One way to handle that is, indeed, to work with chunks of data and not with a big _data array of 100k+ rows (which, even without talking of the query is an array which consume a lot of your available memory).

You should check [Zend_Memory](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.memory.memory-manager.html) for storing your data structure containing all the 100K rows data. This will allow you to manage a virtual objects containing all the rows without having all of them in the real PHP memory. And this will maybe allow you to avoid asynchronous batchs.

Then run your insert query with a limited number of rows each time (so that the query string doesn't get too big). Your 2 codes examples could be used and as said in other response direct access to **mysql_query** could prevent memleaks from Zend_Db or PDO..

If you do not use mysql_query, check that you do not have the **Zend_Db_Profiler** activated on the Db object. If you still see some memory leaks after each request you could try a Zend_Debug of the **Db** object and try to see if some historical data is not stored somewhere (list of past queries for example). Then check the **statement** object as well for the same things.`memory_get_usage` function calls can help you as well debug the leaks.

I would try to `unset($entry);` in the foreach loop end as well.

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is the array size - not anything related to DB. You have to split the $this->_data array IMO.

Comment: hmmm. I can even print the 100k array before the memory to max out, so I guess is not this. I was suggesting the split for smaller chunx for mysql not for php.